# How can I share variables between Web forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a web application on C# .Net and I need to pass variables from form to another form. For example, in the first form I have person class as following;

```
public class Person
{
    private string _Name;
    private string _Surname;
    private string _DateOfBirth;
    private string _Gender;
    private string _Symptoms;

    public Person()
    {
        Name = "Not available";
        Surname = "Not available";
        DateOfBirth = "Not available";
        Gender = "Not available";
        Symptoms = "Not available";
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }
    public string Surname
    {
        get { return _Surname; }
        set { _Surname = value; }
    }
    public string DateOfBirth
    {
        get { return _DateOfBirth; }
        set { _DateOfBirth = value; }
    }
    public string Gender
    {
        get { return _Gender; }
        set { _Gender = value; }
    }
    public string Symptoms
    {
        get { return _Symptoms; }
        set { _Symptoms = value; }
    }
}
```

Then I assign values;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Person MyPerson = new Person();
        MyPerson.Name = txtName.Text;
        MyPerson.Surname = txtSurname.Text;
        MyPerson.DateOfBirth = txtBirth.Text;
        MyPerson.Gender = listGender.Text;
        MyPerson.Symptoms = checked(listSymptoms.Text);
    }
```

So, how can I use these values into another form?

Comment: It's good practice to search for a bit before posting a question here. I know for a fact there are multiple pages on the internet that explain how you can manage this.

Comment: another form should contain a method that accept an object(person class)... for example another form contains public void foo(Person obj) { ///your code } that's it... then you have to pass variable from another form like protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Person MyPerson = new Person();
        MyPerson.Name = txtName.Text;
        MyPerson.Surname = txtSurname.Text;
        MyPerson.DateOfBirth = txtBirth.Text;
        MyPerson.Gender = listGender.Text;
        MyPerson.Symptoms = checked(listSymptoms.Text); foo(MyPersion)
    }

Answer (score 2):

consider Another_form is a new form's class that contain a method should accept an object(person class)... for example

```
public void foo(Person obj) 
{ ///your code }
```

that's it... then you have to pass variable from another form like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
Person MyPerson = new Person(); 
MyPerson.Name = txtName.Text; 
MyPerson.Surname = txtSurname.Text; 
MyPerson.DateOfBirth = txtBirth.Text; 
MyPerson.Gender = listGender.Text; 
MyPerson.Symptoms = checked(listSymptoms.Text); 
another_form f=new another_form();
f.foo(MyPersion) 
}
```

Comment: This code is not a best practice... its just one of the answer of what you asked... so try to use STATE MANAGEMENT concept...

Answer (score 1):

You could make your form produce a `Person` instance instead:

```
// within your form class, whatever it is
public Person CreatePerson()
{
    Person MyPerson = new Person();
    MyPerson.Name = txtName.Text;
    MyPerson.Surname = txtSurname.Text;
    MyPerson.DateOfBirth = txtBirth.Text;
    MyPerson.Gender = listGender.Text;
    MyPerson.Symptoms = checked(listSymptoms.Text);
    return MyPerson;
}
```

Then, from anywhere in your code, call your form instance's `CreatePerson` method:

```
var personFromUI = yourFormInstance.CreatePerson();
```

That is *one* way to do it.

You could also expose the person as a property of your form, or pass a `Person` instance throughout your application objects, be it forms, controls, controllers, etc... while this goes beyond the scope of your question, this would be the preferred way because it **keeps your UI code and your business code separated**.

I'd advise that you look into **[separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)**. You may learn a trick or two there about proper application design.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that you have populated a person object and then on another form you'd like to reference the same instance of that person object? Probably the simplest way would be to store the object in Session and then retrieve it on the second form.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Person MyPerson = new Person();
    MyPerson.Name = txtName.Text;
    MyPerson.Surname = txtSurname.Text;
    MyPerson.DateOfBirth = txtBirth.Text;
    MyPerson.Gender = listGender.Text;
    MyPerson.Symptoms = checked(listSymptoms.Text);
    Session["CurrentPerson"] = MyPerson;

}
```

Personally, I don't normally use session this way and instead build that type of workflow into my apps persistence layer (e.g. Sql Server, Redis).